# Which graphics driver alternatives do I have for Intel HD Graphics?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Having an Arrandale-based notebook with an on-die Intel GPU, which graphics drivers can and should I use?

Comment: I guess none.Xorg uses the module intel,and the kernel will load intel_ips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no proprietary driver for Intel graphics because Intel has made their own drivers free and open source. You don't have any alternatives.

You can use this driver no problem; It supports everything Intel has implemented.

Comment: Small correction: some Intel IGPs based on PowerVR (so non-Intel) cores do require closed source drivers, but those are only used for some Atom CPUs currently, and not for e.g. Arrandale.

Comment: @JanC is that any chip other than the GMA500?

Comment: The GMA500, GMA600 and maybe some other IGPs to come for Atom CPUs/SoCs are based on PowerVR technology (which is also used in many ARM-based and other SoC designs).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Atom CPUs use the GMA3150/3100, and I can't find a single reference to something called GMA600. I'm also quite sure that any Atom Chips integrated graphics are supported by the open source driver. If you can find a reference, perhaps a table of supported chips and where they're used, please edit my answer

Comment: It seems like newer Atoms use an on-die GMA31xx indeed, which is good.  It's the older Atom Z5xx & Z6xx CPUs that used the GMA500 & GMA600 (which have no open source drivers).  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_500_on_Linux) for a bit of info (the GMA600 is listed in the table on that page).