# I need to install the Intel HD 3000 video driver in my PC which is running Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Intel HD 3000 video driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58376/how-do-i-install-the-intel-hd-3000-video-driver)
>   [How to install Intel graphics HD 3000 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134618/how-to-install-intel-graphics-hd-3000-drivers)

I installed in a OEM machine the new ubuntu 12.10 but it seems the HD 2000/3000 accelerator is not installed.

How can install it?

Comment: Why do you thimk it&s not installed?

Comment: @mikewhatever yes, dupe, but not a very useful one. The dupe of that points to an outdated one requiring xorg-edgers, which does not apply to 12.10 with HD3000.

Answer (score 2):

If your system started the driver is installed as intel has open-sourced their   display driver and it's shipped with ubuntu by default.

Verify the installed driver using
`lshw -c video`
It should state provider of the driver in use -  `intel corporation`, if the  driver is correctly installed

You can also check out this information 
[How to review the current state of open source vs. closed source graphics drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178636/how-to-review-the-current-state-of-open-source-vs-closed-source-graphics-driver) 
for a brief overview of display drivers for linux.

Comment: If the intention of this post is to answer the question, I recommend explaining what the output of `lshw -c video` *should* be if the driver you're recommending is installed and in use. Otherwise, this is really a comment requesting information from the OP, rather than an answer providing a possible solution/resolution.